# Agricultural crops data on field level, Europe

Tags: data-request, geospatial, agriculture

I am looking for data sets describing agricultural field crop data across Europe. I have already found:

- The [RPG data set](https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/registre-parcellaire-graphique-rpg-contours-des-ilots-culturaux-et-leur-groupe-de-cultures-majoritaire/) (France) which describes majority crops for each field.
- The [CEH Land Cover plus data set](https://www.ceh.ac.uk/crops2015) (Britain) which describes annual crop type.

However I am struggling to find similar datasets for other European countries (I imagine because of the language barrier). What other field level crop data are available for Europe? What resources are there for finding similar data sets in the future?

Answer (score 1):

For the UK there is an interesting dataset called CROME, have a look here:

https://data.gov.uk/dataset/crop-map-of-england-crome-2016-complete