# Where can I get a vector file (or WMS) showing field boundries on the UK?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, agriculture

I am looking for vector data outlining the agricultural field boundaries in the UK (Specifically Scotland, England and Wales). I have tried all sources of open source data I can find and looked at Ordnance Survey Data.

Ordnance Survey have the data however they package it as part of the Vectormap Local data which costs in excess of £800k for the UK. The actual sub layer is called Rural Boundaries when the Shapefile is extracted.

I need the vector file to allow me to trial an analysis of agricultrual fields. I would like to colourcode the fields dependant on intersecting designations such as flood risk or greenbelt.

If anyone can help, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Agricultural crops data on field level, Europe](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/12237/agricultural-crops-data-on-field-level-europe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the map scale to 1:10,000 or lower you can see field boundaries for England, Wales and Scotland.

http://magic.defra.gov.uk/MagicMap.aspx

The usage is still protected under crown copyright.

[image]

The other option is to extract from Environment Agency (Opendata) Lidar to get a field boundary dataset - this will be time consuming and require data clean up.

https://environmentagency.blog.gov.uk/2017/12/30/uncovering-englands-landscape-by-2020/